# C++ struct doesn't work

Tags: c++

i have a problem.

```
struct Info{
  string name;
  string lastname;
  int BirthDate[];
  int DeathDate[];
}human[2];
......

    for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
        ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate[j];
    }
......
```

When i run this, my compiler stops working.
But if i change

```
for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
        ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate[j];
    }
```

To:

```
for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
        ReadFromFile >> human.BirthDate[j]; //Removing array from struct too
    }
```

Everything works fine. So my question is it possible somehow to do it with array's? For example i have 2 humans, and i want to read their BirthDate's from file. I can't make 2 variables becouse at first i don't know how much humans i'll have in my file.

Comment: Zero length arrays are illegal in C++.

Comment: Design comment:  Why would a person have more than one birthdate and date of death?  I know there is a line in many movies by the villain, "*How many times do I have to kill you.*"  Although some belief systems say that a person can be reborn, so that may be what you are accounting for.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Date is writen like this: 2015 12 28. I just want to put this date into array size of 3

Comment: Dates are often treated as a structure, not as an array.  For example: `struct Date { unsigned int year; unsigned int month; unsigned int day;};`.  If you search around, there may even be libraries (such as *Boost*) that already contain date structures.

Comment: `int BirthDate[];` - i believe, you want it to be `int BirthDate[3];`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yes, but `int BirthDate[];` isn't even a zero-length array.

Comment: "*When i run this, my compiler stops working.*" -- Please describe more clearly what happens. Does your compiler print an error message? If so, include the exact message in the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson My bad.  I was under the impression that was what they are called.  Do you know the correct terminology?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Hmm. g++ treats them as zero-length arrays (and complains about them with `-pedantic`), but normally I'd think that a zero-length array would be written as `int BirthDate[0];`. Since it's not valid in standard C++, it's hard to say what it's called, but I'd think it's an incomplete array type.

Comment: @NathanOliver "ill-formed".  There must be an integer in between the square brackets.

Comment: @KeithThompson That could work

Comment: @M.M I'll keep that in mind for the next time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No need for array's for `BirthDate` and `DeathDate`?

Also: your `j` counts to 3.

Try this:

```
struct Info{
    string name;
    string lastname;
    int BirthDate;
    int DeathDate;
} human[2];
......

    for(int j=0; j < 2; j++){
        ReadFromFile >> human[j].BirthDate;
    }
......
```

**Update**:

> BirthDate contains like this: 2015 12 28 in file.

As Thomas Matthews says:

```
struct MyDate {
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
};

struct Info{
    string name;
    string lastname;
    MyDate BirthDate;
    MyDate DeathDate;
} human[2];
......

    ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate.year;
    ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate.month;
    ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate.day;
......
```

Comment: BirthDate contains like this: 2015 12 28 in file

Comment: What about using a `struct` for a date?  Something like `struct Date (unsigned int year; unsigned int month; unsigned int day;};`.  This would resolve the issue of needing an array; and its more readable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - that should do it (was not clear what was in the file) - post updated.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
struct Date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
struct Info{
    string name;
    string lastname;
    Date BirthDate;
    Date DeathDate;
}human[2];


ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate.day;
ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate.month;
```

Comment: To the OP: Have you got to overloading operators yet?  This would be much clearer with  `std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& stream, Date& date) { return stream >> date.day >> date.month >> date.year; }` then you can write `ReadFromFile >> human[0].BirthDate;`

Comment: Yes, overloading >>  is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you try to create an array without size:

```
int BirthDate[];
int DeathDate[];
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/arrays-cpp?view=msvc-170&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

https://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/7961/

your options are to change it to something like this:

```
#define DATE_SIZE 3
int BirthDate[DATE_SIZE];
int DeathDate[DATE_SIZE];
```

and the loop will be:

```
for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j < DATE_SIZE; j++){
        ReadFromFile >> human[i].BirthDate[j];
    }
}
```

or change it to struct/class, like this:

```
struct date {
int day;
int month;
int year;
}
```

and the struct be:

```
struct Info{
string name;
string lastname;
date BirthDate;
date DeathDate;
} human[2];
```

the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i){
    ReadFromFile >> human[i].BirthDate.day;
    ReadFromFile >> human[i].BirthDate.month;
    ReadFromFile >> human[i].BirthDate.year;
}
```